# Fast indexing of arrays

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

What is the most efficient way to access (and perhaps replace) an entry in a large multidimensional array? I am using something like this inside a loop:

```
tup = (16,45,6,40,3)
A[tup...] = 100
```

but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way. In particular, is there a way I can avoid using `...`?

Comment: For a specific entry you can precompute `ii=sub2ind(size(A),tup...)` and then use `A[ii]`

Comment: I believe that is doing exactly the same calculation as `A[tup...]`

Comment: it is doing the same calculation but **precomputes** it once, and saves the computation in the loop (this could be one interpretation of question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not always a penalty involved with splatting, but determining where it is efficient isn't always obvious (or easy).  Your trivial example is actually just as efficient as writing `A[16,45,6,40,3] = 100`.  You can see this by comparing

```
   function f(A)
       tup = (16,45,6,40,3)
       A[tup...] = 100
       A
   end
   function g(A)
       A[16,45,6,40,3] = 100
       A
   end
julia> code_llvm(f, Tuple{Array{Int, 5}})
# Lots of output (bounds checks).
julia> code_llvm(g, Tuple{Array{Int, 5}})
# Identical to above
```

If there was a splatting penalty, you'd see it in the form of allocations.  You can test for this with the `@allocated` macro or by simply inspecting `code_llvm` for a reference to `@jl_pgcstack` — that's the garbage collector, which is required any time there's an allocation.  Note that there is very likely other things in a more complicated function that will also cause allocations, so it's presence doesn't necessarily mean that there's a splatting pessimization. But if this is in a hot loop, you want to minimize all allocations, so it's a great target… even if your problem isn't due to splatting. You should also be using `@code_warntype`, as poorly typed code will definitely pessimize splats and many other operations.  Here's what will happen if your tuple isn't well typed:

```
   function h(A)
       tup = ntuple(x->x+1, 5) # type inference doesn't know the type or size of this tuple
       A[tup...] = 100
       A
   end
julia> code_warntype(h, Tuple{Array{Int,5}})
# Lots of red flags
```

So optimizing this splat will be highly dependent upon how you construct or obtain `tup`.

Comment: Note that I don't talk about the indexing itself at all.  That's because the actual indexing is really quite fast.  For normal arrays, the biggest difference between indexing with the full dimensionality (e.g., 5 indices) and a linear index (just 1) is the five bounds checks.  Those can be avoided with `@inbounds` if you're absolutely certain the access is safe.  For special array types (like SubArrays), it is *significantly* faster to avoid linear indexing.

Comment: I guess my question is whether there is an efficient way of converting from tuples to indices. For my problem, I will never have to access `SubArray`s, only specific elements of the full `Array`. I recall reading somewhere that splatting is not very efficient (perhaps for an earlier version of Julia). Plus `@code_warntype` does not work with splat.

Comment: @amrods - My point is that, for the example you provided, there is absolutely no additional overhead involved in unpacking the tuple to individual indices with a splat.  You can also wrap the tuple in a `CartesianIndex(tup)`, but I think the cases where that has no overhead will overlap with the cases where splatting a tuple has no overhead.

Answer (score 5):

To iterate over multidimensional arrays, it is recommended to do `for index in eachindex(A)`; see e.g.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/CF_Iphgt2Wo/V-b31-6oxSkJ

If `A` is a standard array, then this corresponds to just indexing using a single integer, which is the fastest way to access your array (your original question):

```
A = rand(3, 3)

for i in eachindex(A)
   println(i)
end
```

However, if `A` is a more complicated object, e.g. a subarray, then `eachindex(A)` will give you a different, efficient, access object:

```
julia> for i in eachindex(slice(A, 1:3, 2:3))
           println(i)
       end
```

gives

```
CartesianIndex{2}((1,1))
CartesianIndex{2}((2,1))
```

etc.

Comment: Hmm, I should probably subscribe to those public service announcements... However, `eachindex` will give me an iterator for each position in `A`. I guess I just need a way to convert from tuple to indexes.

Comment: If you want a linear index as well, the easiest is just `k = 0; for i in eachindex(A); k += 1; blah blah` and now you have a linear index as well as a cartesian index.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to index a multidimensional array is to index it linearly.
[Base.Base.linearindexing](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/arrays/#Base.Base.linearindexing) is a related function from `Base` module to find **most efficiently accesses way** to elements of an array.

```
julia> a=rand(1:10...);
julia> Base.Base.linearindexing(a)
Base.LinearFast()
```

one could use `ii=sub2ind(size(A),tup...)` syntax to convert a tuple of index to one linear index or `for i in eachindex(A)` to traverse it.

Comment: There are many array types for which linear indexing is definitely **not** the fastest way to index into them.  If you already have a multidimensional index tuple, the most efficient way to index with it is… just index with it directly! If needed, it'll be converted to a linear index by the standard library.  But that may not be necessary, and even if it is, it's a performance bug if that's not the fastest way to do it.